# array to string convert in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

Hello i want convert array to string convert in cakephp.This is my code for retrieve data from table.

```
 $date_time_search=$this->Temptrip->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Temptrip.from_area as search'),'conditions'=>array('Temptrip.created >=' => $first1,'Temptrip.created <=' => $last2)));

$this->set('date_time_search', $date_time_search);
```

My .ctp code here- 
I have completely done my output as array as Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Temptrip] => Array
                (
                    [search] => High Commission of Iran, Road No 75, Dhaka
                )

        )
```

but i want to my output same as-[0] => High Commission of Iran, Road No 75, Dhaka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
use Cake\Utility\Hash;
...
...
$date_time_search=$this->Temptrip->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Temptrip.from_area as search'),'conditions'=>array('Temptrip.created >=' => $first1,'Temptrip.created <=' => $last2)));
$results = Hash::extract($date_time_search, '{n}.Temptrip.search');
$this->set('date_time_search', $results);
```

Source : [Hash::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CHash::extract)